# Can I have one log scale y-axis and one normal second y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will start off by saying I know this is generally frowned upon because it can be VERY misleading.  However in my case I am just showing a timing relationship on the x-axis (the actual values on the second y-axis are fairly arbitrary in terms of my interpretations).

My first y-axis should be in log10 to show patterns in low concentration data.  My second y-axis should just be "normal" with no transformation.  Is this possible to do in ggplot?  I found this previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248016/second-y-axis-with-other-scale), but the answer doesn't pertain to my issue necessarily.

Here is what I got going on now in my script:

```
toy$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(all.data$date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))
dis$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(discharge$date, format = "%m/%d/%y"))

p.ch4 <- ggplot(toy, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=type)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type, fill=type), color = "black", size=4) +
  geom_bar(data=dis, aes(x=date,y=discharge*20), inherit.aes = FALSE,
           stat='identity', alpha=.25) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Location:", values = c(23:25)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Location:", 
                    values = c("orange2","olivedrab2","steelblue2")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Location:", 
                     values = c("orange2","olivedrab2","steelblue2")) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./20, name = "Discharge (cms)")) +
  labs(y = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')), x = "", color = "Location", 
       shape = "Location") 
print(p.ch4)
```

AAAND here is some toy data that mimics mine (but is much smaller/shorter):

```
> dput(toy)
structure(list(date = c("11/5/17", "11/6/17", "11/6/17", "1/5/18", 
"1/5/18", "1/5/18", "3/27/18", "3/28/18", "3/29/18", "6/20/18", 
"6/20/18", "6/20/18"), type = c("4cm", "12cm", "0cm", "4cm", 
"12cm", "0cm", "4cm", "12cm", "0cm", "4cm", "12cm", "0cm"), variable = c("ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", "ch4", 
"ch4", "ch4"), value = c(0.37, 0.7, 0.43, 10.21, 0.3, 0.29, 32.59, 
7.1, 7.42, 117.09, 2.4, 1.54)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

> dput(dis)
structure(list(date = c("11/5/17", "1/5/18", "3/27/18", "6/20/18"
), discharge = c(0.64, 0.33, 0.31, 3.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

TIA!!!

Comment: This duplicate question has 249 votes and roughly 350k views. It appears on top position when googling exactly your question. Can you kindly explain why this is not answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something likes this:

```
p.ch4 <- ggplot(toy, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=type)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=type, fill=type), color = "black", size=4) +
  geom_bar(data=dis, aes(x=date,y=discharge*20), inherit.aes = FALSE,
           stat='identity', alpha=.25) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Location:", values = c(23:25)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Location:", 
                    values = c("orange2","olivedrab2","steelblue2")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Location:", 
                     values = c("orange2","olivedrab2","steelblue2")) +
  scale_y_log10(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./20, name = "Discharge (cms)", labels = scales::label_number())) +
  labs(y = expression(paste('Methane (', mu, 'M)')), x = "", color = "Location", 
       shape = "Location") 
print(p.ch4)
```

Output:

[image]